# How do I create an element that overlap both modal and overlay inside bootstrap 5 modal

Tags: image, modal-dialog, element, overlay, bootstrap-5

Please can anyone guide me on how I can create an element that overlaps both the modal and its overlay inside bootstrap 5 modal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Absolute [positioning](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/position/#position-values) (here applied via Bootstrap's `position-absolute`.
2. Negative top margin equal to half the badge's height and standard centering with `left` and `transform`.
3. [Flex layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/) for centering badge content.
4. Top [margin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) on the header and title elements to push them down below the badge (margin classes don't go large enough for just one to do the job).

```js
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal');

myModal.show();
```

```css
.modal-badge {
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="position-absolute modal-badge">Hi!</div>

      <div class="modal-header mt-4">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5 mt-2" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```